# Error Launching IDEA_How do i can make it work

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having trouble running the following program.
I have downloaded it from the following link https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?_ga=2.219925081.1961582015.1677922450-335394254.1677922450#section=windows
"community edition".
After the installation was done , when I went to run it, it gave me the following message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rr1P.png)
I have installed the program it mention but the problem remains

I'm trying to implement the program

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: What is your OS? Is it 32- or 64-bit?